# Listings, coloured VBA with backslash

Tags: listings, classicthesis

I'm currently writing my master thesis and have some extensive Visual Basic codes which I want to include in the appendix. The template I'm using for my thesis is "classicthesis" (from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis). I already adjusted some things to personalize the code but I don't understand how to overcome this problem.

The problem is this. The VBA code that I've written is complicated. I therefore want to highlight the code in my appendix with the same colours as in Visual Basic. In my VBA-code, I also define some filepaths where I use the backslash in a string. This backslash is the problem. Generally in LaTex a backslash is reckognized for a command. In this case it isn't, I want to highlight it using the same rules as the rest of the VBA-code. Can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem without adjusting the VBA code?

The appendix .tex-file is:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\input{../classicthesis-config}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\lstset{language=[Visual]Basic}
\lstinputlisting[caption=macro]{../Codes/Module1c.txt}
\end{document}
```

The file Module1.bas (partly):

```
'Starting strings
Analysis = Worksheets("Loading").Range("C3")

'File paths
FilePathData = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Analysis & "\" & LCase(Analysis) & ".DAT"
FilePathOutput = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Analysis & "\" & UCase(Analysis) & ".OUT"
FilePathPostprocess = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Analysis & "\" & Analysis & ".FVC"

'Clear the cells where information is placed
TableCorner.Resize(TableCorner.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 10).Clear
```

The results looks like this:
[image: Appendix A]

However, I want to have it look like this:
[image: Appendix A (manually adjusted)]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Okay, I changed the Latex-code as you say

Comment: *This backslash is the problem. Generally in LaTex a backslash is reckognized for a command. In this case it isn't, I want to highlight it using the same rules as the rest of the VBA-code.* I don't understand; I don't see any difference in the way backslashes are rendered between your two screenshots...

Comment: The problem is the coloured code. After the backslash the comments in the VBA-code aren't recognized as comments and therefore not coloured green. Same goes for the functions LCase and UCase, they aren't coloured blue. It makes the use of the listing-language [Visual]Basic completely useless. The code is rendered as I want to but the colours given to the code aren't correct.

Comment: I made the second screenshot by replacing all the backslashes by a double backslash and then removing one of the two backslashes in Paint and moving the "s

Comment: Your question is going to be difficult to answer, unless you turn your code into [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). In particular, we don't know the contents of `classicthesis-config`.